# Trouble with pandas iterrows and loop counter

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a dataset containing the US treasury curve for each day over a few years. Rows = Dates, Columns = tenor of specific treasury bond (3 mo, 1 yr, 10yr, etc)

I have python code that loops through each day and calibrates parameters for an interest rate model. I am having trouble looping through each row via iterrows and with my loop counter. The goal is to go row by row and calibrate the model to that daily curve, store the calibrated parameters in a dataframe, and then move onto the next row and repeat.

```
def do_calibration_model1():
    global i
    for index, row in curves.iterrows():      
        day = np.array(row) #the subsequent error_fxn uses this daily curve
        calibration()
    i += 1

def calibration():
    i = 0
    param = scipy.brute(error_fxn, bounds...., etc.)
    opt = scipy.fmin(error_fxn, param, xtol..., ftol...)
    calibration.loc[i] = np.array(opt) # store result of minimization (parameters for that day)
```

The code works correctly for the first iteration but then keeps repeating the calibration for the first row in the dataframe (curves). Further, it does not store the parameters in the next row of the calibration dataframe. I view the first issue as relating to the iterrows while the second is an issue of the loop counter.

Any thoughts on what is going wrong? I have a Matlab background and find the pandas setup to be very frustrating.

For reference I have consulted the links below to no avail.

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0212/

http://nipunbatra.github.io/2015/06/pandas-iteration/

Per Jason's comment below I have updated the code to:

```
def do_calibration_model1():
    global i
    for index, row in curves.iterrows():
        for i in range(0,len(curves)):      
            day = np.array(row) #the subsequent error_fxn uses this daily curve
            param = scipy.brute(error_fxn, bounds...., etc.)
            opt = scipy.fmin(error_fxn, param, xtol..., ftol...)
            calibration.loc[i] = np.array(opt) # store result of minimization  (parameters for that day)
            i += 1
```

The revised code now places the appropriate parameters in each row of the calibration dataframe based on the loop counter.

*However, it still does not move to the second (or subsequent rows) of the curves dataframe for the pandas iterrows function.

Comment: I've edited my answer below to address the iterrows part of your question. Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Each time `calibration` is called, you set `i = 0`. As a result, when you call `calibration.loc[i] = np.array(opt)`, what is being written is item 0 of calibration. The variable `i` is never actually anything except 0 in this function.

In function `do_calibration_model1()`, you declare `global i` and then augment `i` by one at the end of the function call. I'm not sure what this `i` counter is meant to accomplish. Perhaps you think that the `i` in `do_calibration_model1()` is updating the value of the `i` variable in the `calibration()` function, but this is not the case. Given that there is no `global i` statement in `calibration()`, the `i` in this function is a local variable.

Regarding `iterrows`, I don't think you need the embedded for loop that cycles through the length of curves. Here's a quick example to show you how `iterrows` works:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 4), columns=['A','B','C','D'])

new = pd.DataFrame({'sum': [],
                    'mean': []})
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    temp = {'sum': sum(row), 'mean': np.mean(row)}
    new = new.append(temp, ignore_index=True)
```

In the above, `df` looks like this:

```
          A         B         C         D
0 -2.197018  1.905543  0.773851 -0.006683
1  0.675442  0.818040 -0.561957  0.002737
2 -0.833482  0.248135 -1.159698 -0.302912
3  0.784216 -0.156225 -0.043505 -2.539486
4 -0.637248  0.034303 -1.405159 -1.590045
5  0.289257 -0.085030 -0.619899 -0.211158
6  0.804702 -0.838365  0.199911  0.210378
7 -0.031306  0.166793 -0.200867  1.343865
```

And the `new` dataframe populated through the `iterrows` loop looks like this:

```
       mean       sum
0  0.118923  0.475693
1  0.233566  0.934262
2 -0.511989 -2.047958
3 -0.488750 -1.954999
4 -0.899537 -3.598148
5 -0.156707 -0.626830
6  0.094157  0.376626
7  0.319621  1.278485
```

Note that using `append` here makes unnecessary the use of an `i` counter and simplifies the code.

Returning to your code, I suggest something like the following:

```
def do_calibration_model1():
    callibration = pd.DataFrame({'a': [],
                                 'b': []})
    for index, row in curves.iterrows():   
        day = np.array(row)
        param = scipy.brute(error_fxn, bounds...., etc.)
        opt = scipy.fmin(error_fxn, param, xtol..., ftol...)
        temp = {'a': ..., 'b': ...}   # put opt values into dict
        callibration = calibration.append(temp, ignore_index=True)
    return callibration
```

In this step `callibration = pd.DataFrame({'a': [], 'b': []})` you will need to set up the dataframe to ingest `opt`. Previously, you transformed `opt` to a numpy array, but you will need to arrange the values of `opt` so they fit your callibration dataframe, in the same way that I did for temp here: `temp = {'sum': sum(row), 'mean': np.mean(row)}`.